# jQuery UI's Sortable update event not firing

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

I'm using jQuery UI's Sortable and I would like to call a function on update. Here's the code I'm trying now.

```
$(".sortable").sortable({
    handle: '.handle'
    , start: function (event, ui) {
        console.log('started sorting ' + $(event.srcElement).index());
        prev_sortable_index = $(event.srcElement).index();
        $('.sortable li:not(.ui-state-highlight)').each(function () {
            prev_list_elements.push($(this));
            new_sort_order.push($(this).index());
        });
        console.log(new_sort_order);
    }
    , update: function (event, ui) {
        alert("testing");
    }
});
```

After sorting, I do not receive the alert message. If I move 'update' above 'start', I have the same results. I have tried adding the alert to the start event, stop event, and update event. I do not get any errors or warnings, just the update event does not seem to fire. I also made sure I do not have any preventDefault or stopPropagation interfering with my targeted elements.

Edit: Adding HTML

```
<ul class="sortable no-margin no-padding" style="list-style:none;">
   <li class="item green-row"><span class="handle"><img src="~/Images/handle.png" style="width:14px; margin-top:2px;" /></span>
       <table style="width:97%;">
          <tr style="background:none;">
             <td style="width:130px;">Plan Check Fee</td>
             <td style="width:120px;">Plan Check</td>
             <td style="width:80px;">-</td>
             <td style="width:103px;">$1200.00</td>
             <td style="width:113px;">-</td>
             <td style="width:92px;">$100.00</td>
             <td style="width:100px;">$1100.00</td>
             <td style="width:88px;">$1100.00</td>
          </tr>
       </table>
    </li>
    <li class="item green-row"><span class="handle"><img src="~/Images/handle.png" style="width:14px; margin-top:2px;" /></span>
       <table style="width:97%;">
          <tr style="background:none;">
             <td style="width:130px;">Plan Check Fee</td>
             <td style="width:120px;">Plan Check</td>
             <td style="width:80px;">-</td>
             <td style="width:103px;">$1200.00</td>
             <td style="width:113px;">-</td>
             <td style="width:92px;">$100.00</td>
             <td style="width:100px;">$1100.00</td>
             <td style="width:88px;">$1100.00</td>
          </tr>
       </table>
    </li>                                               
</ul>
```

Comment: Can you produce a demo on jsFiddle showing this behavior?

Comment: I'm unable to replicate the issue I'm having with jsFiddle. There must be something that is killing my alerts. I added an alert to the start event, and that does not work either.

Comment: Here is as far as I have gotten http://jsfiddle.net/n3v19wb5/1/ but there is an outer var called `prev_list_elements` that you didn't include in your code

Comment: Here's a fiddle of what I am attempting to accomplish. When I run this exact code on my page, I do not get the alert message. Any idea what could be killing this on my site? http://jsfiddle.net/dmv9jaua/

Comment: Actually I added some code and got this working: http://jsfiddle.net/n3v19wb5/2/

Comment: @JasonSperske I used your exact code on my page, and I don't receive the alerts.

Comment: Did you check to make sure jquery-ui.js is loaded? if your are using a schema-less URL like `<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>` then it won't work if you just double clicking on an `.html` file, it needs to be running on a web server (it's the only obvious thing I can think of)

Comment: @JasonSperske yes, it is loaded, and the sorting works correctly. I'm puzzled since the sorting works, and I do not receive any errors or alerts.

Comment: Can you add your html? I think with the sorting working, this is a much harder problem :/

Comment: Added the html to my question @JasonSperske

Comment: Updated JSFiddle seems to work: http://jsfiddle.net/n3v19wb5/4/ what errors do you see in the JavaScript console?

Comment: It does work for me in all fiddles, but not on my page. I do not receive any errors in the JavaScript Console. @JasonSperske

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was finally able to solve my issue, and it turns out it was a conflict in JavaScript references. I previously used jquery.sortable.js, then went back to using the sorting functionality of jQuery UI's sort, but failed to remove the reference to jquery.sortable.js.

Comment: If the issue was caused by a mistake that can't be reproduced by the info shared in question, I suggest deleting it since it isn't going to help anyone...

Comment: @TJ It seems like other people have struggled with this same issue, as I saw many questions very similar with hardly any answers. I was finally able to find a post on another forum suggesting that a reference conflict could be the cause. Since that was my issue, and the answer was not posted here on SO, I thought I should keep the question posted.

Comment: I get clue for my problem with the help of the answer. Its shows me way to fix my problem. So please don't delete the answer. May be someone else will get help from this.